# What are use-cases of non-surjective total functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Total functions are so "interesting" in Mathematics that the term "total" is often implicit. Therefore, it is common to use "function" to refer to a "total function" and only mention "partial function" or "potentially partial function" if the special need arises.

My question is, why don't surjective functions get the same benefit? For every function $f: A \to B$ there exists a unique function $f_s: A \to Im_f(A)$ such that $\forall x \in A. f(x) = f_s(x)$. And that function is surjective. For all purposes that I can think of, $f_s$ can do the job just fine. Is there any great loss in expressivity for common use cases that I am overlooking which warrant talking about non-surjective functions by default? What would be those use-cases?

Edit: I am not trying to challenge the status quo. I am just trying to find examples which emphasize the interest in the non-surjectivity of a function.

Comment: Yes: what you suggest would be a royal pain in most settings. Typically we want to consider families of functions from some object (set, space, group, etc.) $X$ to some object $Y$, and the codomain $Y$ is more important than the ranges of the individual functions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That is my intuition as well. I am not challenging the status quo here. I am just trying to find concrete examples of such uses. Ideally ones which emphasize the non-surjectivity.

Comment: Functions spaces. Endomorphism groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of situations where you care about functions that need not be surjective (but where you do care about their codomain).  Here are just a couple examples.

Given a set $X$, a *metric* on $X$ is a function $d:X\times X\to[0,\infty)$ which satisfies certain axioms that say that $d(x,y)$ behaves like the "distance" from $x$ to $y$.  A set $X$ together with a metric $d$ on $X$ is called a *metric space*.  Metric spaces play a huge role in modern mathematics and are ubiquitous in analysis and topology.  And there are plenty of natural and important examples of metrics which are not surjective.  For instance, if you take $X=[0,1]$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, the image of $d$ is just $[0,1]$, rather than all of $[0,\infty)$.  If all functions were surjective, you would have to awkwardly define a metric to be a function from $X\times X$ to some subset of $[0,\infty)$, when that subset is usually of little interest.

Given a topological space $X$ and a point $x_0\in X$, the *fundamental group* of $X$ at $x_0$ is the set of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=x_0$, modulo a certain equivalence relation (roughly, $f$ and $g$ are equivalent if you can "continuously deform" $f$ into $g$).  As the name suggests, this set has a natural group structure, and this group is hugely important in topology and geometry.  It is essential here that the codomain of $f$ is the space $X$ (the idea is that $f$ represents a "curve" drawn in the space $X$), but $f$ is not required to be surjective.  The definition of the equivalence relation also involves certain maps with codomain $X$ which are not required to be surjective.

The common theme in these examples is that we are not just talking about one particular function (for which you could always just change the codomain to make it surjective), but we are interested in studying an entire class of functions with some common properties.  One of the important common properties is that these functions take value in a certain set (such as $[0,\infty)$, or our chosen topological space $X$), but there is no reason for them to be surjective onto that set and they may have different images.  By allowing functions to not be surjective we can just specify their common codomain without caring about what their image is.

Comment: Your two definitions (for metric space and for topological space) seem to assume that $f$ and $f_s$ from the question are the same function. Otherwise your first definition excludes metrics like (for example) the geodesic distance on the unit sphere, whose codomain may be defined as $[0, π]$. In the Set category (in which your definitions live) it matters whether a morphism goes from $X \times X$ to $[0, π)$ or to $[0, \inf)$ because they would be two different morphisms.

Comment: But my point is that there is no reason to use the "surjective version" of the metric.  That is, it is at least as useful (if not more useful) to define the geodesic distance on the unit sphere to be a function $S^2\times S^2\to [0,\infty)$, rather than a function $S^2\times S^2\to [0,\pi]$.  For all purposes you ever care about, you want to treat all metrics the same regardless of whether their image is all of $[0,\infty)$ or just some subset of it, so you should define them all to have codomain $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my point regarding category theory (which is at the essence of the question itself) if you claim "for all purposes you ever care about".

Comment: If you have a question about category theory, you should state clearly what that question is.  Your question as written is "why is it useful to define 'function' to mean 'not-necessarily-surjective function'?", and an answer to that question is obviously going to be about how functions are actually _used_ in math (hence, "for all purposes you ever care about").  This has basically nothing to do with category theory (except in that category theory is one branch of math).

Comment: Because otherwise, a function defined as $g_s: S^2 \times S^2 \to [0, π]$ could __not__ be a metric just because of its codomain being different than $[0, \infty)$. Even if otherwise it would satisfy the axioms a the metric. Such a function would only be a metric according to your definition if it was _the same function as_ $g: S^2 \times S^2 \to [0, \infty). \forall (x, y) \in S^2 \times S^2. g_s(x, y) = g(x, y)$ .

Comment: Yes, and that is the standard mathematical convention.  What's wrong with that?  Given any such function $g$, you can always compose it with the inclusion map $[0,\pi]\to[0,\infty)$ to get an actual metric.  And why do you want to define $g$ to have codomain $[0,\pi]$ instead of $[0,\infty)$ to begin with?  That doesn't make it any easier to define $g$ (if anything, it makes it harder...).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48590/discussion-between-victor-savu-and-eric-wofsey).